# Let X Geo(p1) and Y Geo(p2)

Tags: probability

Let X $Geo(\frac{1}{4})$ and Y $Geo(\frac{1}{2})$. The random variables X and Y are independent. Compute P(X + Y = 3).

I don't know how to compute it, I calculate that for a Geometric Distribution $P(X + Y = K) = (K-1) \cdot p^2 \cdot (1-p)^{K-2}$ but then I don't know how to include both Geometric Distribution, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an expression for the RHS of:$$P(X+Y=3)=\sum_{k=0}^3P(X=k\wedge Y=3-k)=\sum_{k=0}^3P(X=k)P(Y=3-k)$$
Here the second equality rests on independence.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, can you explain what should I do? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you understand the first equality?

Comment: The one that I derive yes, but I don't know how can I combine it with the equation that you wrote to arrive at the correct answer

Comment: I meant: do you understand the first equality in my answer? If you do, then do you understand the second equality in my answer? For the utmost RHS you can find an expression on base of the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Ahh, no I don't, can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: If $A=A_0\cup A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$ and the $A_k$ are mutually exclusive (i.e. at most one of the events $A_k$ can occur) then $P(A)=P(A_0)+P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)$. Do you agree? Now observe that this can be applied on the events $A=\{X+Y=3\}$ and $A_k=\{X=k\text{ and } Y=3-k\}$ for $k=0,1,2,3$. That results in the first equality in my answer.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote make sense but I still don't get how can I convert your expression in the probability equation that I need to resolve the problem, where do I have to put the two geometric distributions?

Comment: Can you find $P(X=k) $ and $P (Y=k) $ for $k=0,1,2,3$? If so then you can substitute these values in RHS of equality in my answer. Then calculate and the result is $P (X+Y=3) $ which is the LHS of the equality and is what are asking for. The distributions of $X$ and $Y $ are known so I really do not see what makes this difficult for you.

Comment: Yes,$ P(X=K) = p \cdot (1-p)^{K-1}$, where p is 1\4 for the first distribution and 1/2 for the second. I can calculate this probability for various K but then (and also for which K values should I calculate it)? How can I compute $P(Y = 3- K)$? Can you show me the steps, it's a bit complicated for me to follow, thanks!

Comment: So as you said you can calculate  $p_k=P (X=k) $ and also $q_k=P (Y=k) $ for $k=0,1,2,3$. Then do that, and based on that calculate  $p_0q_3+p_1q_2+p_2q_1+p_3q_0$. Then you are ready since the outcome equals  $P (X+Y=3) $.

Comment: I tried your method but then the final result is not equal to the solution 5/32, and I also notice that in my formula sheet the geometric distribution is correct for a k value from 1 and not from 0, it's true?

Comment: There are 2 different [geometric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). One counts the number of failures that occur before the first success has arrived (so there $P(X=0)>0$). The other counts the number of trials needed for arriving at the first success (so there $P(X=0)=0$). You are apparantly dealing with that one. In both cases $P(X+Y=3)=p_0q_3+p_1q_2+p_2q_1+p_3q_0$ but here $p_0=q_0=0$ so that it simplifies to $P(X+Y=3)=p_1q_2+p_2q_1$. What values did you find for $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$? The outcome is indeed $\frac5{32}$.

Comment: Ohh I got it, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.